# vue-meteor-tracker not fetching current user

Tags: vue.js, meteor

I am new to both Vuejs and Meteorjs so please excuse if these are newbie questions or the syntax is off.
I am trying to use `vue-meteor-tracker` to update the login\register button to logout but I am unable to do so. The `Meteor.user` always comes as undefined.
What am I missing?

**base.js:**

```
    import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
export default {
      meteor: 
      {
        $lazy: true,
        $subscribe: 
        {
          'currentUser': function() {
            return Meteor.user();
          },
      'currentUserId': function() {
        return Meteor.userId();
      }
        },
      },
    }
```

**plugins.js**

```
import VueMeteorTracker from 'vue-meteor-tracker';
Vue.use(VueMeteorTracker);
```

**MainNavBar.vue**

```
<li v-if="($parent.currentUserId==null)">
  <router-link v-bind:to="{ name: 'register' }">Register</router-link></li>
<li v-else>
  <router-link v-bind:to="{ name: 'register' }">Log out</router-link></li>
<script>
import base from '../base';
export default 
{  
  extends: base,  
  components:{
  },
  mounted() 
  {
    console.log(this.$parent.currentUserId);
  }
}
</script>
```

**Login.Vue:**

```
<script>
import '../api/methods.js';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import base from './base';
export default
{
extends: base,
methods: 
  { 
    LoginUserForDomain() 
    {
      Meteor.call('loginUserForDomain', this.user.email, this.user.password, this.user.domain, 
        (error, result) => 
        {
          if(result && result.userId && result.domain) 
          {                 
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password);
            this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard', params: { domain: result.domain }});                   
            return;
          }
        }
        );
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my reply in the [Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/using-vue-meteor-tracker-to-update-meteor-user-does-not-work/50954/2?u=wildhart), you are `$subscribing` to `currentUser` and `currentUserId` instead of defining them as reactive data.  Also, you don't need to publish/subscribe to the current user's userId because it is always available in the client as `Meteor.userId()`.

`Meteor.userId()` is a reactive data source and you can convert it into a Vue reactive property using `vue-meteor-tracker` like this: e.g. within **App.vue**:

```
<script>
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
export default {
  meteor: {
    currentUserId() {
      return Meteor.userId();
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Then you can use it within any template as, e.g. `v-if="$root.currentUserId"`, or within any component's code as `this.$root.currentUserId`.

In this simple example I have used the root Vue instance as an easily accessible global data store, but it's more widely accepted to use a [dedicated data store](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html), or use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

Comment: Thank you @wildhart for your replies and your handholding. I had couple of follow up questies wrt Meteor. If I register a user on the server, would the client know about the same without meteorjs's  publish/subscribe mechanism? Or is it the accepted practise to do work related to account management on the client and let the meteorjs framework/minimingo take care of syncing it up to the mongodb backend?

Comment: I've never heard of anyone logging a user in on the server. What would be the purpose of that?  You can CREATE a user on the server, but the client would not know about that unless they are SUBSCRIBED to a set of user data which would include the new user.

Comment: the application that I am developing is a multitenant application.  When a user registers he would need to select a domain that has not been registered before. All of this work has been done server side since doing it client side would lead to too many server calls and potential client side hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.user() will always return undefined when you're not logged in. So your login logic isn't working. I'm not sure what you're doing, but you should be using 'Meteor.loginWithPassword' to do your logging in on the client. What's 'loginUserForDomain' for?

I don't understand `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password);` as both 'email' and 'password' would be undefined (should it be this.user.email?). Also does 'this.user.email' console.log anything?

Comment: Thank you @kc gibson for your input. I had edited the code heavily before posting it.

Comment: If the posted code is wrong can you please update the code snippets.

Comment: I will do that later in the evening.